# Business Mapping API and deleted applications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

According [this document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids) Facebook will not provide real user IDs in API. Now I have to use Business Mapping API if I need to run cross-app promotions.

What will happen with Mapping API if one of my applications will be blocked or deleted?
Will I have possibility to get user ID in deleted app when I will use Mapping API?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will not.

Comment: What reason would there be for the mapping API to work in that situation?

Comment: It's decision of project manager. Before we use one FB application ID for all our mobile apps - iOS, Android, Windows Phone. But accidently our application ID was blocked for a few days. It made big problems for our business.

After we started to use different app IDs for different platforms. But in this case we need Mapping API even if one of our app IDs will be blocked again.